# Convert a string into a list?

Tags: python, list

The following is my string that I have copied from a text file. I want to replace the last column using the new data.

```
CROPWAT 8.0 Climate data
 0   6

Ananthapur
-99.90
 -99.90  -99.90
 -99.9 -99.9  -99.9  -99.9  -99.9 -99.9     3.90
 -99.9 -99.9  -99.9  -99.9  -99.9 -99.9     4.77
 -99.9 -99.9  -99.9  -99.9  -99.9 -99.9     5.78
 -99.9 -99.9  -99.9  -99.9  -99.9 -99.9     6.30
 -99.9 -99.9  -99.9  -99.9  -99.9 -99.9     6.17
 -99.9 -99.9  -99.9  -99.9  -99.9 -99.9     5.06
 -99.9 -99.9  -99.9  -99.9  -99.9 -99.9     4.49
 -99.9 -99.9  -99.9  -99.9  -99.9 -99.9     4.41
 -99.9 -99.9  -99.9  -99.9  -99.9 -99.9     4.49
 -99.9 -99.9  -99.9  -99.9  -99.9 -99.9     4.12
 -99.9 -99.9  -99.9  -99.9  -99.9 -99.9     3.68
 -99.9 -99.9  -99.9  -99.9  -99.9 -99.9     3.48
```

`new_data = ['3.10', '3.71', '4.46', '4.83', '5.02', '4.72', '4.09', '3.96', '3.84', '3.54', '3.15', '2.93']`

I have to achieve this task without losing the formating of my original data. I am using `.replace` command but the code is long. If there is a smarter way to do this, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you Nick for editing my question. It looks more understandable now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the string `s` into the header (the first 6 rows) and the table (the remaining rows):

```
rows = s.split("\n")
header = rows[:6]
table = rows[6:]
```

Replace the tail of each row in the table with the new value: for each row, find the rightmost space, take a slice of the row from the beginning to that space, and concatenate it with the patch.

```
new_table = [(row[:row.rfind(" ")+1] + patch) 
             for row,patch in zip(table, new_data)]
```

Recombine the header and the updated table:

```
"\n".join(header + new_table)
```

Comment: This is working fine. Can you please explain the second step that deals with new_table?

Comment: I added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Baseline would be separate the col[6] and replace it with new list. You can use .split( ) to split the file. Sample example

```
try:
  fhand = open('/pathtoyourfile')
except:
print('file not found !!!')
   exit()

new_data = ['3.10', '3.71', '4.46', '4.83', '5.02', '4.72', '4.09', '3.96', '3.84', '3.54', '3.15', '2.93']
for value,line in zip(new_data,fhand):
    elements = line.split( )
    print("{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}".format(elements[0], elements[1],elements[2],elements[3],elements[4],elements[5] ,value,elements[6]))
```